# How many applicants do Stack Overflow Jobs posts that explicitly allow remote typically get?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I see that Stack Overflow Jobs allows me to search for jobs that allow 100% remote. That's great. Some of these jobs look really nice, but I've been wondering what the competition is like.

I know these jobs look great to other candidates, too, so how many applicants does the "typical" remote posting on Stack Overflow Jobs get?

(I do realise that "typical" is a murky term to use here.)

Comment: This kind of thing would be an interesting (if discouraging) type of information to publish publicly...

Comment: Regardless of whether it is interesting or discouraging, it would be *useful*

Comment: It would be cool to know. Not sure whether the raw number would tell you much, though: with remote jobs, applying is trivial for a huge number of people (because no geographical/visa constraints; basically all you need is a computer) and you still don’t know how many of those folks play even roughly in the same league as you

Comment: That's the challenge: Proving you're in the big league.

Comment: You'll never find out, it is a trade secret.  An probably quite discouraging, another reason they won't tell.

Comment: This question is too general. Jobs for what? With what skills requirements? What is the prior experience requirement? Is native language skill necessary? Is there a time-zone requirement? If you're looking for a Fortran developer that speaks fluent Farsi and has a minimum of 20 years experience, and is in the New Zealand time zone..  the answer is: Not many. If you're looking for someone who "knows CSS" and can work at least 10 hours per week, then lots.

Comment: A personal anecdote: I've gotten responses from two separate companies that say they've gotten "dozens of applications a day"/"hundreds of applications" when I received a rejection notice. Both of these jobs, though, had the same posting on multiple job boards, so it's safe to assume all of those didn't come through SO Jobs.